# Kendo UI Grid multi level hierarchy (n-levels of hierarchy)

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am using the Kendo UI Grid and currently display parent child records appropriately.  However, it turns out that i will actually need to display n-levels vs. strictly parent-child.  Not every record will have children, but some will have multiple levels.

Current grid code:

```
 var jgrid = $("#boxesgrid").kendoGrid({
        columns: [
            {
                field: "JobId",
                hidden: true
            },
            {
                field: "PercentComplete",
                hidden: true
            },
            {
                field: "JobStatusId",
                hidden: true
            },
            {
                field: "AppName",
                title: "App",
                template: "<span>${AppName}</span><img class='health-img-r' id=app-${JobId} title='health' src='' alt='health_png' />",
                width: "5%",
                editable: false,
                sortable: false
            },
            {
                field: "JobName",
                title: "Box Name",
                width: "17%",
                filterable: false
            },
            {
                field: "StartTime",
                title: "Start Time",
                width: "14%",
                filterable: false
            },
            {
                field: "EndTime",
                title: "End Time",
                width: "14%",
                filterable: false
            },
            {
                field: "JobStatusId",
                title: "Status",
                template: "<img class='health-img-l' id=app-${JobId} title='health' src='' alt='health_png' /><span>${JobStatus}</span>",
                editable: false,
                filterable: false
            }
        ],
        sortable: {
            mode: "single",
            allowUnsort: true
        },
        pageable: {
            pageSizes: [50],
            numeric: true,
            refresh: true,
            pageSize: 50
        },
        autoBind: false,
        scrollable: false,
        resizable: true,
        detailInit: detailInit,
        dataSource: boxesDataSource,
        dataBound: function () {
            var grid = this;
            grid.tbody.find(">tr").each(function () {
                var row = $(this).closest("tr");
                var model = grid.dataItem(row);
                var img = $(this).find("img");
                if (model.JobStatusId == 4 && model.PercentComplete < 100) {
                    img.attr("src", function() {
                        return imgSrc + imgGreen;
                    });
                } else if (model.JobStatusId == 4) {
                    img.attr("src", function() {
                        return imgSrc + imgAmber;
                    });
                } else if (model.JobStatusId == 7) {
                    img.attr("src", function() {
                        return imgSrc + imgIce;
                    });
                } else if (model.JobStatusId == 8) {
                    img.attr("src", function() {
                        return imgSrc + imgHold;
                    });
                } else if (model.JobStatusId == 5) {
                    img.attr("src", function() {
                        return imgSrc + imgBlue;
                    });
                } else {
                    img.attr("src", function() {
                        return imgSrc + imgRed;
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    }).data("kendoGrid");
```

Current child grid:

```
function detailInit(e) {
        $("<div/>").appendTo(e.detailCell).kendoGrid({
            dataSource: {
                transport: {
                    read: {
                        url: "/api/BoxJobs"
                    },
                    parameterMap: function (data) {
                        data.parentid = e.data.JobId;
                        data.appid = e.data.AppId;
                        return kendo.stringify(data);
                    }
                },
                schema: {
                    model: { id: "JobId" }
                },
                serverPaging: true,
                serverFiltering: true,
                serverSorting: true
            },
            scrollable: false,
            sortable: true,
            columns: [
                {
                    field: "JobId",
                    hidden: true
                },
                {
                    field: "PercentComplete",
                    hidden: true
                },
                {
                    field: "JobStatusId",
                    hidden: true
                },
                {
                    field: "JobName",
                    title: "Job Name",
                    template: "<span>${JobName}</span><img class='health-img-l' id=app-${JobId} title='health' src='' alt='health_png' />",
                    width: "23%",
                    filterable: false,
                    sortable: false
                },
                {
                    field: "StartTime",
                    title: "Start Time",
                    width: "10%",
                    editable: false,
                    filterable: false,
                    sortable: false
                },
                {
                    field: "EndTime",
                    title: "End Time",
                    width: "10%",
                    editable: false,
                    filterable: false,
                    sortable: false
                },
                {
                    field: "ElapsedTime",
                    title: "Elapsed</br>Time",
                    width: "4%",
                    editable: false,
                    filterable: false,
                    sortable: false
                },
                {
                    field: "MeanRunTime",
                    title: "Mean Run</br>Time",
                    width: "3.5%",
                    editable: false,
                    filterable: false,
                    sortable: false
                },
                {
                    field: "PredecessorJobName",
                    title: "Previous Job",
                    width: "17%",
                    filterable: false,
                    sortable: false
                },
                {
                    field: "JobStatusId",
                    title: "Status",
                    template: "<img class='health-img-l' id=app-${JobId} title='health' src='' alt='health_png' /><span>${JobStatus}</span>",
                    editable: false,
                    filterable: false,
                    sortable: false
                }
            ],
            dataBound: function () {
                var grid = this;
                grid.tbody.find(">tr").each(function () {
                    var row = $(this).closest("tr");
                    var model = grid.dataItem(row);
                    var img = $(this).find("img");
                    if (model.JobStatusId == 4 && model.PercentComplete < 100) {
                        img.attr("src", function() {
                            return imgSrc + imgGreen;
                        });
                    } else if (model.JobStatusId == 4) {
                        img.attr("src", function() {
                            return imgSrc + imgAmber;
                        });
                    } else if (model.JobStatusId == 7) {
                        img.attr("src", function() {
                            return imgSrc + imgIce;
                        });
                    } else if (model.JobStatusId == 8) {
                        img.attr("src", function() {
                            return imgSrc + imgHold;
                        });
                    } else if (model.JobStatusId == 5) {
                        img.attr("src", function() {
                            return imgSrc + imgBlue;
                        });
                    } else {
                        img.attr("src", function() {
                            return imgSrc + imgRed;
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

Sample top level data:

```
   {"Total":638,
"Data":[
    {"JobId":1,"AppId":1,"AppName":"APP1","LobId":2,"LobName":"LOB2","JobName":"NRS_COL_BOX","JobType":"box","TimeZone":"Chicago (Central Standard Time)","ParentJobName":null,"ParentJobId":null,"PredecessorJobName":null,"PredecessorJobId":null,"StartTime":"6/2/2014 5:00:02 PM","EndTime":"","ElapsedTime":"00:58:31","JobStatusId":4,"JobStatus":"Running","MeanRunTime":"06:57:04","PercentComplete":14.00,"TotalCount":638.0,"Children":3}
    ]
}
```

Sample 2nd level data:

```
[
{"JobId":63,"AppId":1,"AppName":"APP1","LobId":2,"LobName":"LOB2","JobName":"NRS_COL2_BOX","JobType":"box","TimeZone":"Chicago (Central Standard Time)","ParentJobName":"NRS_COL_BOX","ParentJobId":1,"PredecessorJobName":null,"PredecessorJobId":null,"StartTime":"6/2/2014 5:00:06 PM","EndTime":"","ElapsedTime":"00:58:27","JobStatusId":4,"JobStatus":"Running","MeanRunTime":"06:57:00","PercentComplete":14.00,"TotalCount":0.0,"Children":3},
{"JobId":64,"AppId":1,"AppName":"APP1","LobId":2,"LobName":"LOB2","JobName":"NRS_COL1_BOX","JobType":"box","TimeZone":"Chicago (Central Standard Time)","ParentJobName":"NRS_COL_BOX","ParentJobId":1,"PredecessorJobName":null,"PredecessorJobId":null,"StartTime":"6/2/2014 5:00:06 PM","EndTime":"","ElapsedTime":"00:58:27","JobStatusId":4,"JobStatus":"Running","MeanRunTime":"01:42:17","PercentComplete":57.00,"TotalCount":0.0,"Children":2},
{"JobId":65,"AppId":1,"AppName":"APP1","LobId":2,"LobName":"LOB2","JobName":"NRS_COL3_BOX","JobType":"box","TimeZone":"Chicago (Central Standard Time)","ParentJobName":"NRS_COL_BOX","ParentJobId":1,"PredecessorJobName":null,"PredecessorJobId":null,"StartTime":"6/2/2014 5:00:06 PM","EndTime":"6/2/2014 5:07:42 PM","ElapsedTime":"00:07:36","JobStatusId":5,"JobStatus":"Success","MeanRunTime":"00:03:17","PercentComplete":100.0,"TotalCount":0.0,"Children":5}
]
```

Sample 3rd level data:

```
[
{"JobId":265,"AppId":1,"AppName":"APP1","LobId":2,"LobName":"LOB2","JobName":"NRS_COL2_S_CLEAN1","TimeZone":"Chicago (Central Standard Time)","ParentJobName":"NRS_COL2_BOX","ParentJobId":63,"PredecessorJobName":"NRS_COL2_S_TOUCH1","PredecessorJobId":266,"StartTime":"","EndTime":"","ElapsedTime":"00:58:31","JobStatusId":7,"JobStatus":"On Ice","PercentComplete":null,"Children":0},
{"JobId":266,"AppId":1,"AppName":"APP1","LobId":2,"LobName":"LOB2","JobName":"NRS_COL2_S_TOUCH1","TimeZone":"Chicago (Central Standard Time)","ParentJobName":"NRS_COL2_BOX","ParentJobId":63,"PredecessorJobName":null,"PredecessorJobId":null,"StartTime":"","EndTime":"","ElapsedTime":"00:58:31","JobStatusId":7,"JobStatus":"On Ice","PercentComplete":null,"Children":0},
{"JobId":267,"AppId":1,"AppName":"APP1","LobId":2,"LobName":"LOB2","JobName":"NRS_COL2_A_ZFINSNAMA","TimeZone":"Chicago (Central Standard Time)","ParentJobName":"NRS_COL2_BOX","ParentJobId":63,"PredecessorJobName":"NRS_COL2_S_CLEAN1","PredecessorJobId":265,"StartTime":"6/2/2014 5:02:02 PM","EndTime":"","ElapsedTime":"00:58:31","JobStatusId":4,"JobStatus":"Running","PercentComplete":null,"Children":0}
]
```

I have no problem with the traditional parent-child hierarchy, but I'm struggling with even how I go about making the detail template behave for it's children.

I would like the template to be appropriate for child/grandchild display - no dropdown indicator if it does not have additional children.  I assume that i can evaluate the data on databound, but I'm just not seeing how to do it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It took a while, but I finally worked out an answer with some guidance from the peeps at Telerik. I was just having the hardest time getting my head around the solution.

Vladimir (at Telerik) suggested that I use a custom ajax call in the detailInit function using a function on success to determine if I had child data to consider.  Since I needed the detail grid no matter what, I moved the child check into another function that creates the detail grid.  If I find child data, I add a detailInit parameter to the new grid. If not, I simply render the new detail grid.

The ajax initDetail function:

```
function detailInit(e) {
            var eventData = e;
            $.ajax({
                url: apiUrl + "ProcessJobs",
                type: "POST",
                data: {BoxId: e.data.JobId, AppId: e.data.AppId}, 
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(data, status, xhr) {
                    initializeDetailGrid(eventData, data);
                }
            }
```

The function to build the new detail grid with the check for children:

```
function initializeDetailGrid(e, result) {
            var moreChildren = result[0].HasChildren;
            var gridBaseOptions = {
                dataSource: result,
                scrollable: false,
                sortable: true,
                columns: [
                    {
                        field: "ParentJobId",
                        title: "Parent Job"
                    },
                    {
                        field: "JobId",
                        title: "Job Id"
                    },
                    {
                        field: "JobName",
                        title: "Job Name",
                    },
                    {
                        field: "JobStatus",
                        title: "Status"
                    },
                    {
                        field: "JobStatusId",
                        title: "Status Code"
                    },
                    {
                        field: "HasChildren",
                        title: "Has Children"
                    },
                    {
                        field: "ChildrenCount",
                        title: "Child Jobs"
                    }
                ]
            };

            var gridOptions = {};
            if (moreChildren) {
                gridOptions = $.extend({}, gridBaseOptions, { detailInit: detailInit });
            } else {
                gridOptions = gridBaseOptions;
            };
            $("<div/>").appendTo(e.detailCell).kendoGrid(gridOptions);
        };
```

For completeness, here is the full page and example data from the sample project. It is a .Net MVC4 based website, using Web API services for data and Kendo UI for the client.

Here is the page code:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "n-level Grid";
}

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var isParent, appId, lobId, boxId;
        var apiUrl = '@ViewBag.ApiUrl';

        var lobDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: apiUrl + "Lob"
                }
            },
            schema: {
                model: {
                    id: "LobId",
                    hasChildren: "HasChildren"
                }
            }
        });

        var appsDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: apiUrl + "App"
                },
                parameterMap: function (data, action) {
                    if (action === "read") {
                        data.lobid = lobId;
                        data.parent = isParent;
                        return data;
                    } else {
                        return data;
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        var filterDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: apiUrl + "Theme"
                }
            },
            schema: {
                model: { id: "FilterId" }
            }
        });

        var boxesDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: apiUrl + "Process"
                },
                parameterMap: function (data) {
                    data.appid = appId;
                    data.parent = isParent;
                    data.lobid = lobId;
                    return kendo.stringify(data);
                }
            },
            schema: {
                data: "Data",
                total: "Total",
                model: { id: "JobId" }
            },
            serverPaging: true,
            serverFiltering: true,
            serverSorting: true
        });

        var lobnav = $("#lobnav").kendoTreeView({
            select: function (e) {
                var tree = this;
                var src = tree.dataItem(e.node);
                lobId = src.LobId;
                isParent = src.HasChildren;
            },
            change: function (e) {
                appsDataSource.read();
            },
            dataSource: {
                transport: {
                    read: {
                        url: apiUrl + "Lob"
                    }
                },
                schema: {
                    model: {
                        id: "LobId",
                        hasChildren: "HasChildren"
                    }
                }
            },
            loadOnDemand: false,
            dataTextField: "LobName"
        });

        var appnav = $("#lobapp").kendoListView({
            selectable: "single",
            autoBind: false,
            change: function () {
                var idx = this.select().index();
                var itm = this.dataSource.view()[idx];
                appId = itm.AppId;
                boxesDataSource.query({
                    page: 1,
                    pageSize: 10
                });
            },
            template: "<div class='pointercursor'>${AppName}</div>",
            dataSource: appsDataSource
        });

        var jobsfilter = $("#jobfilter").kendoListView({
            selectable: "single",
            loadOnDemand: false,
            template: "<div class='pointercursor' id=${FilterId}>${FilterName}</div>",
            dataSource: filterDataSource,
            dataBound: function () {
                var dsource = $("#jobfilter").data("kendoListView").dataSource;
                if (dsource.at(0).FilterName !== "All") {
                    dsource.insert(0, { FilterId: 0, FilterName: "All" });
                }
            },
            change: function () {
                var itm = this.select().index(), dataItem = this.dataSource.view()[itm];
                var appDs = appsDataSource.view(), apps = $("#lobapp").data("kendoListView"),
                    selected = $.map(apps.select(), function (item) {
                        return appDs[$(item).index()].AppName;
                    });
                if (selected.length > 0) {
                    if (dataItem.FilterId !== 0) {
                        var $filter = new Array();
                        $filter.push({ field: "JobStatusId", operator: "eq", value: dataItem.FilterId });
                        jgrid.dataSource.filter($filter);
                    } else {
                        jgrid.dataSource.filter({});
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        var jgrid = $("#boxesgrid").kendoGrid({
            columns: [
                {
                    field: "AppName",
                    title: "App"
                },
                {
                    field: "JobId",
                    title: "Job Id"
                },
                {
                    field: "JobName",
                    title: "Job Name",
                },
                {
                    field: "JobStatus",
                    title: "Status"
                },
                {
                    field: "JobStatusId",
                    title: "Status Code"
                },
                {
                    field: "HasChildren",
                    title: "Has Children"
                },
                {
                    field: "ChildrenCount",
                    title: "Child Jobs"
                }
            ],
            sortable: {
                mode: "single",
                allowUnsort: true
            },
            pageable: {
                pageSizes: [10],
                numeric: true,
                refresh: true,
                pageSize: 10
            },
            autoBind: false,
            scrollable: false,
            resizable: true,
            detailInit: detailInit,
            dataSource: boxesDataSource
        }).data("kendoGrid");

        function detailInit(e) {
            var eventData = e;
            $.ajax({
                url: apiUrl + "ProcessJobs",
                type: "POST",
                data: {BoxId: e.data.JobId, AppId: e.data.AppId}, 
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(data, status, xhr) {
                    initializeDetailGrid(eventData, data);
                }
            });
        };

        function initializeDetailGrid(e, result) {
            var moreChildren = result[0].HasChildren;
            var gridBaseOptions = {
                dataSource: result,
                scrollable: false,
                sortable: true,
                columns: [
                    {
                        field: "ParentJobId",
                        title: "Parent Job"
                    },
                    {
                        field: "JobId",
                        title: "Job Id"
                    },
                    {
                        field: "JobName",
                        title: "Job Name",
                    },
                    {
                        field: "JobStatus",
                        title: "Status"
                    },
                    {
                        field: "JobStatusId",
                        title: "Status Code"
                    },
                    {
                        field: "HasChildren",
                        title: "Has Children"
                    },
                    {
                        field: "ChildrenCount",
                        title: "Child Jobs"
                    }
                ]
            };

            var gridOptions = {};
            if (moreChildren) {
                gridOptions = $.extend({}, gridBaseOptions, { detailInit: detailInit });
            } else {
                gridOptions = gridBaseOptions;
            };
            $("<div/>").appendTo(e.detailCell).kendoGrid(gridOptions);
        };
    });
</script>

<div class="col-md-2">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">Line of Business</div>
        <div class="panel-body" id="lobnav"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">Application</div>
        <div class="panel-body" id="lobapp"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">Filter</div>
        <div class="panel-body" id="jobfilter">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-10">
    <div id="boxesgrid"></div>
</div>
```

The data is actually hardcoded for this sample app, but I still return it via Web API.  Here is a sample of the highest level data:

```
new Process {JobId = 108, AppId = 1, AppName = "App1", LobId = 2, LobName = "Lob2", JobName = "job_108", ParentJobName = null, ParentJobId = null, JobStatusId = 4, JobStatus = "Running", ChildrenCount = 3, HasChildren = true},
new Process {JobId = 109, AppId = 1, AppName = "App1", LobId = 2, LobName = "Lob2", JobName = "job_109", ParentJobName = null, ParentJobId = null, JobStatusId = 5, JobStatus = "Success", ChildrenCount = 4, HasChildren = true},
new Process {JobId = 110, AppId = 1, AppName = "App1", LobId = 2, LobName = "Lob2", JobName = "job_110", ParentJobName = null, ParentJobId = null, JobStatusId = 4, JobStatus = "Running", ChildrenCount = 2, HasChildren = true},
new Process {JobId = 111, AppId = 1, AppName = "App1", LobId = 2, LobName = "Lob2", JobName = "job_111", ParentJobName = null, ParentJobId = null, JobStatusId = 5, JobStatus = "Success", ChildrenCount = 5, HasChildren = true},
```

Here is some second level data (child data):

```
new Process {JobId = 1037, AppId = 1, AppName = "App1", LobId = 2, LobName = "Lob2", JobName = "job_1037", ParentJobName = "job_109", ParentJobId = 109, JobStatusId = 4, JobStatus = "Running", ChildrenCount = 0, HasChildren = false},
new Process {JobId = 1038, AppId = 1, AppName = "App1", LobId = 2, LobName = "Lob2", JobName = "job_1038", ParentJobName = "job_109", ParentJobId = 109, JobStatusId = 4, JobStatus = "Running", ChildrenCount = 0, HasChildren = false},
new Process {JobId = 1039, AppId = 1, AppName = "App1", LobId = 2, LobName = "Lob2", JobName = "job_1039", ParentJobName = "job_110", ParentJobId = 110, JobStatusId = 4, JobStatus = "Running", ChildrenCount = 2, HasChildren = true},
new Process {JobId = 1040, AppId = 1, AppName = "App1", LobId = 2, LobName = "Lob2", JobName = "job_1040", ParentJobName = "job_110", ParentJobId = 110, JobStatusId = 4, JobStatus = "Running", ChildrenCount = 2, HasChildren = true},
```

Some of the 3rd level data (grandchildren):

```
new Process {JobId = 5000, AppId = 1, AppName = "App1", LobId = 2, LobName = "Lob2", JobName = "job_5000", ParentJobName = "job_1039", ParentJobId = 1039, JobStatusId = 5, JobStatus = "Success", ChildrenCount = 0, HasChildren = false},
new Process {JobId = 5001, AppId = 1, AppName = "App1", LobId = 2, LobName = "Lob2", JobName = "job_5001", ParentJobName = "job_1039", ParentJobId = 1039, JobStatusId = 5, JobStatus = "Success", ChildrenCount = 0, HasChildren = false},
new Process {JobId = 5002, AppId = 1, AppName = "App1", LobId = 2, LobName = "Lob2", JobName = "job_5002", ParentJobName = "job_1040", ParentJobId = 1040, JobStatusId = 5, JobStatus = "Success", ChildrenCount = 0, HasChildren = false},
new Process {JobId = 5003, AppId = 1, AppName = "App1", LobId = 2, LobName = "Lob2", JobName = "job_5003", ParentJobName = "job_1040", ParentJobId = 1040, JobStatusId = 5, JobStatus = "Success", ChildrenCount = 0, HasChildren = false},
new Process {JobId = 5004, AppId = 1, AppName = "App1", LobId = 2, LobName = "Lob2", JobName = "job_5004", ParentJobName = "job_1041", ParentJobId = 1041, JobStatusId = 5, JobStatus = "Success", ChildrenCount = 1, HasChildren = true},
```

And so on...

It is working correctly for 4 levels in my testing.  There are formatting issues with the multiple nested grids that I will be addressing.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I just have one question: were you able to keep the hierarchy open when the table needed to be updated? Or did you not need to do that for what you were doing? I cant seem to keep mine open.

Comment: I don't keep it open on update because that wasn't a requirement in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this question is still open, but a simple solution is to use recursion in the "DetailInit" function, like below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <base href="https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/hierarchy">
    <style>html { font-size: 14px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }</style>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.1.117/styles/kendo.common-material.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.1.117/styles/kendo.material.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.1.117/styles/kendo.material.mobile.min.css" />

    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.1.117/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.1.117/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
    

</head>
<body>

        <div id="example">
            <div id="grid"></div>          
            <script>

var myData = [{ item: 0, title:"Meat" , items:[
                { item: 0.1, title:"Beef"},
                { item: 0.2, title:"Chicken"},
              ]}, 
              { item: 1, title:"Vegetables", items:[
                { item: 1.0, title:"Carrot"},
                { item: 1.1, title:"Pies", items:[
                  { item: 1.11, title:"Pie1"},
                  { item: 1.12, title:"Pie2"},
                  { item: 1.13, title:"Pie3"}
                 ]},
              ]}
             ];
              
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    var element = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                        dataSource: {
                            data: myData
                        },
                        height: 600,
                        sortable: true,
                        pageable: true,
                        detailInit: detailInit1,
                        dataBound: function() {
                            this.expandRow(this.tbody.find("tr.k-master-row").last());
                        },
                        columns: [
                            {
                                field: "item",
                                title: "ID",
                                width: "110px"
                            },
                            {
                                field: "title",
                                title: "Food",
                                width: "110px"
                            }
                        ]
                    });
                });

                function detailInit1(e) {                  
                    $("<div/>").appendTo(e.detailCell).kendoGrid({
                        dataSource: {
                            data: e.data.items  //data is the current position item, items is its child items
                        },
                        scrollable: false,
                        sortable: true,
                        pageable: true,   
                        detailInit: detailInit1,
                        dataBound: function() {
                            this.expandRow(this.tbody.find("tr.k-master-row").last());
                        },
                        columns: [
                            {
                                field: "item",
                                title: "ID",
                                width: "110px"
                            },
                            {
                                field: "title",
                                title: "Food",
                                width: "110px"
                            }
                        ]
                    });
                }
              
            </script>
        </div>


</body>
</html>
```