# Kendo Grid Foreign Key Column with large dataset

Tags: kendo-ui, grid, foreign-keys

We are using in our App Kendo Grid with a Foreign Key column like this example
http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/foreignkeycolumn
Our dataset is very large so we are using ServerPaging and ServerFiltering in order to do LazyLoading.
Our problem is the data for the ForeignKey Column.
In all the examples in the Telerik Website the ForeignKey column data is preloaded when the page loads.
This is ok for a few number of records, but it's a very big problem if the FK column has thousands of records and you also want to support editing.
Any ideas?

Comment: Have you considered using n-tier or sub grids?

Comment: n-tier? Can you add more details?

Comment: [n-tier or multi-level grids - a solution i put in place to do something similar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24004905/kendo-ui-grid-multi-level-hierarchy-n-levels-of-hierarchy)

Comment: No, you are describing another problem.

Comment: The sample you linked to shows a drop-down column with the list of foreign-key based data.  What you are describing as your problem makes no sense in that regard.  I'm suggesting a different solution but I am obviously working with a very limited sense of what you are trying to do.

Comment: Maybe you could expand on how you want to present the related data sets.

Comment: My problem is also described here http://www.telerik.com/forums/foreign-key-option-doesn-t-work . And from the comments I see that there is no out of the box solution

Comment: You asked for ideas.  I'm aware of the limitation of the foreign-key issue - which is why I solved it using n-tier grids - because it fit how I needed to present the data.  The point of the foreign key in the grid (as the example shows) is based on a simple lookup.  What you are implying (because there is not a clear problem/question in your description) is displaying an entire set of data for editing based on a foreign key - a completely different task.

Comment: I'm attempting to help clarify what you are trying to do because as worded, your question isn't clear and concise.  If you could clearly describe what you are trying to do, you will get better help.

Comment: Let's take for example this demo http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/foreignkeycolumn Categories are a predefined small data set. I want to do the same thing but the categories are loaded via a web service that returns key value pairs and the number of categories are a few thousand. So lazy loading should be applied on Categories as well

Comment: You actually want to load a few thousand choices in a dropdown?

Comment: O Yes, which is actually a real world scenario. A dropdownlist holds the data of a foreign key column. Imagine tables with thousands of rows and have Foregn Key Columns. When you load the data of this table on a Grid you are enabling ServerPaging and Server Scrolling in order to load the data of the table in parts. You need to do this on FK columns as well when you are editing them

Comment: Sorry, but I wouldn't ever do that.  That drop-down control becomes effectively unusable.

Comment: [Some thoughts on dropdowns with large number](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/33618/what-is-an-effective-way-to-allow-user-select-from-a-list-of-thousands-of-custom) or [some ux thoughts on dropdowns](http://baymard.com/blog/drop-down-usability)

Comment: Thank you for your try. We finally manged to do what we wanted. Unfortunately what we needed is not offered out of the box with Kendo. We used this example http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/editing-custom as a starting point by it required too much customization both on server side as well as on client side in order to achieve firtering and sorting as well