# How to get the raw data from kendo dataSource?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-grid

I am getting kendo grid data from backend and setting it to kendo grid options 
`alignedProcessesToRiskGridOptions` now data is displaying in the grid , but i also wanted to get raw data to write some logic, How can i get data from dataSource or directly calling `RiskService` AngularJs factory and assign it to `var gridData`?

ctrl.js

```
   $scope.alignedProcessesToRiskGridOptions = RiskService.alignedProcessToRiskGrid();
    $scope.alignedProcessesToRiskGridOptions.dataSource = RiskService.getAlignedProcessesToRiskGridDataSource($stateParams.riskId);
    gridData = $scope.alignedProcessesToRiskGridOptions.dataSource.data();
    console.log('RISK DATA', gridData);
```

factory.js

```
getAlignedProcessesToRiskGridDataSource: function(riskKey) {
        var countNew = 0;
        return new kendo.data.DataSource({
                    type: 'json',
                    serverPaging: true,
                    serverSorting: true,
                    serverFiltering: true,
                    transport: {
                        read: function(options) {
                            var gridSearchObject = {
                                skip: options.data.skip,
                                take: options.data.take,
                                pageSize: options.data.pageSize,
                                page: options.data.page,
                                sorting: options.data.sort,
                                filter: options.data.filter
                            };
                            return $http.post(
                                'app/risk/rest/allAlignedProcessesToRisk/' + riskKey, gridSearchObject).success(
                                function(data) {
                                    countNew = data.totalCount;
                                    options.success(data.resultDTOList);
                                });
                        }

                    },
```

Comment: What is written to the console for `console.log('RISK DATA', gridData);`?

Comment: it returns the function but no data

Comment: Does it write `RISK DATA undefined`? Does it show `gridData` as an object? Does it write an empty string?

Comment: gridData as an object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the kendo documentation, there are at least a couple ways to get at the actual data from a datasource.

[There is the `view` method](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#methods-view)

> Returns the data items which correspond to the current page, filter,
>   sort and group configuration. Compare with the data method, which will
>   return data items from all pages, if local data binding and paging are
>   used.

[There is the `data` method](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#methods-data)

> Gets or sets the data items of the data source.
>
> If the data source is bound to a remote service (via the transport
>   option) the data method will return the service response. Every item
>   from the response is wrapped in a kendo.data.ObservableObject or
>   kendo.data.Model (if the schema.model option is set).
>
> If the data source is bound to a JavaScript array (via the data
>   option) the data method will return the items of that array. Every
>   item from the array is wrapped in a kendo.data.ObservableObject or
>   kendo.data.Model (if the schema.model option is set).

Since you are using the `data` method, you should be able to access the data via the properties and methods of the resulting object.

You should be able to check the `length` of `gridData` via `console.log(gridData.length)`, as well checking any individual object within the data via an array index `console.log(gridData[0])`.  Further you should be able to check properties of the objects via `console.log(gridData[0].firstProperty)`.

If none of these work, then it is likely because the datasource is not being checked with the context of `query` or `fetch`.  If you [check out this example](http://dojo.telerik.com/oTami), you will see that the data is being evaluated inside of the `fetch` function.

You can find more information about [the Kendo DataSource in their online documentation](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource).

Lastly, you can see an example of the different ways I use the Kendo datasource in [this question about the kendo grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24004905/kendo-ui-grid-multi-level-hierarchy-n-levels-of-hierarchy/24310780#24310780).