# Setting params in Kendo UI Grid when calling a rest service [Workaround]

Tags: rest, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a Kendo UI Grid that is calling a rest service. It works fine, as long as I do not try to use any params.

I know the the rest service is correct, as I can call it from a browser, and get correct results [depending on the param I send]. Also, when I look the server log I see that it is calling the rest service with no params.

My code is below:

```
document).ready( function() {


         var crudServiceBaseUrl = "rsPC.xsp",
                    dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                        transport: {
                            read:  {
                                url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "/PCByStatus",
                                filter: {field: "status", value: "2" }                                  
                                dataType: "json",
                            update: {
                                url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "/PC/Update",
                                dataType: "json"
                            },
                            destroy: {
                                url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "/PC/Destroy",
                                dataType: "json"
                            },
                            create: {
                                url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "/PC/Create",
                                dataType: "json"
                            },
                            parameterMap: function(options, operation) {
                                if (operation !== "read" && options.models) {
                                    return {models: kendo.stringify(options.models)};
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        batch: true,
                        pageSize: 20,
                        scrollable: {
                        virtual: true
                          },
                        height: 543,
                        schema: {
                            model: {
                                id: "PCId",
                                fields: {
                                    PCId: {type:"string"},
                                    serialNumber: {type: "string"},
                                    officeLoc: {type: "string"},
                                    unid: {type:"string"},
                                    model: {type:"string"},
                                    checkInDate: {type: "string"}
                                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });


    // Grid
    grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid( {   
        dataSource: dataSource,
        columns : [ {
            field : "serialNumber",
            title : "Serial Number"
        }, {
            field : "model",
            title : "Model"
        }, {
            field : "officeLoc",
            title : "Office Location"
        }, {
            field : "checkInDate",
            title : "Check In Date",
            template: "#= kendo.toString(kendo.parseDate(checkInDate, 'yyyy-MM-dd'), 'MM/dd/yyyy') #"


        } ],

        pageable: {
             refresh: true,
             pageSizes: true,
             buttonCount: 5
         },
        dataBound : addExtraStylingToGrid,  
        reorderable : true,
        filterable : true,
        scrollable : true,
        selectable : true,
        sortable : true,            
    });
```

I still cannot get this to work and am a bit stumped.

I have two rest services, one returns all data, one takes "status" as a part and return a subset of the data that equals the parm.

The URL is:

http://localhost/scoApps/PC/PCApp.nsf/rsPC.xsp/PCByStatus?status=2

When entered into browser I get the correct number of records.

So I changed the code (see below). I have included all of the code for the CSJS:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    // Double Click On row
    $("#grid").on(
            "dblclick",
            " tbody > tr",
            function() {
                var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
                var row = grid.dataItem($(this));
                window.location.replace("xpFormPC.xsp" + "?key=" + row.unid + "target=_self");                  
            });

    // Add hover effect
    addExtraStylingToGrid = function() {
        $("table.k-focusable tbody tr ").hover( function() {
            $(this).toggleClass("k-state-hover");
        });
    };

    // Search
    $("#search").keyup( function() {
        var val = $('#search').val();
        $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.filter( {
            logic : "or",
            filters : [ {
                field : "serialNumber",
                operator : "contains",
                value : val
            }, {
                field : "officeLoc",
                operator : "contains",
                value : val
            }, {
                field : "model",
                operator : "contains",
                value : val
            } ]
        });
    });

    var crudServiceBaseUrl = "rsPC.xsp",
    dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        transport: {
        read:  {
        url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "/PCByStatus",
        dataType: "json"
    },
    update: {
        url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "/PC/Update",
        dataType: "json"
    },
    destroy: {
        url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "/PC/Destroy",
        dataType: "json"
    },
    create: {
        url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "/PC/Create",
        dataType: "json"
    },
    parameterMap: function(options, operation) {
        if (operation == "read"){
            options.field = "status"
                options.value = "2"
                    return options;
        }
        if (operation !== "read" && options.models) {
            return {models: kendo.stringify(options.models)};
        }
    }
    },
    batch: true,
    pageSize: 20,
    scrollable: {
        virtual: true
    },
    height: 543,
    schema: {
        model: {
        id: "PCId",
        fields: {
        PCId: {type:"string"},
        serialNumber: {type: "string"},
        officeLoc: {type: "string"},
        unid: {type:"string"},
        model: {type:"string"},
        checkInDate: {type: "string"}
    }
    }
    }
    });

    // Grid
    grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid( {   
        dataSource: dataSource,
        columns : [ {
            field : "serialNumber",
            title : "Serial Number"
        }, {
            field : "model",
            title : "Model"
        }, {
            field : "officeLoc",
            title : "Office Location"
        }, {
            field : "checkInDate",
            title : "Check In Date",
            template: "#= kendo.toString(kendo.parseDate(checkInDate, 'yyyy-MM-dd'), 'MM/dd/yyyy') #"


        } ],
        pageable: {
        refresh: true,
        pageSizes: true,
        buttonCount: 5
    },
    dataBound : addExtraStylingToGrid,  
    reorderable : true,
    filterable : true,
    scrollable : true,
    selectable : true,
    sortable : true     
    });

    // Edit
    function onEdit(e) {
    }

    // Change
    function onChange(args) {
        var model = this.dataItem(this.select());
        ID = model.ID;
    }
    ;

});
```

What am I doing wrong?

=========================================

I have a workaround. Or possibly this is the way it is supposed to be done.

```
var crudServiceBaseUrl = "rsPC.xsp", dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource(
        {
            transport : {
            read : {
            url : crudServiceBaseUrl
            + "/PCByStatus?status=2",
            dataType : "json"
        },
```

Now I just construct the URL I want. Not so elegant I suppose, but it works.

Comment: You should post the final code as your answer and then accept it.

Answer (score 1):

I have a workaround. Or possibly this is the way it is supposed to be done.

```
var crudServiceBaseUrl = "rsPC.xsp", dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource(
        {
            transport : {
            read : {
            url : crudServiceBaseUrl
            + "/PCByStatus?status=2",
            dataType : "json"
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

`Filter` is used for client side data unless you set `serverFiltering` to true.

Here is the `filter` [kendo documentation](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-filter) and the `serverFiltering` [documentation](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-serverFiltering).

I use `parameterMap` when I need to send parameters that are not created by filtering the control that I'm using. [The kendo documentation](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-transport.parameterMap) provides an example using `parameterMap`.

Here is an example of how I've used it in the past:

```
var appsDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
        read: {
            url: apiUrl + "App"
        },
        parameterMap: function (data, action) {
            if (action === "read") {
                data.lobid = lobId;
                data.parent = isParent;
                return data;
            } else {
                return data;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Try changing the `parameterMap`:

```
parameterMap: function(options, operation) {
    if (operation == "read"){
        options.field = "status";
        options.value = "2";
        return options;
    }
    if (operation !== "read" && options.models) {
        return {models: kendo.stringify(options.models)};
    }
}
```

and update the `read` definition to remove `filter`. One thing to consider is that you are not returning anything from the `read` method if it doesn't meet the criteria of not being a read and options is not null. That leaves out any other combination that isn't obviously handled in your existing code.

Comment: whipdancer, thank you for the reply. I have looked at the docs and tried everything and still cannot get this to work. I have added more explanation and code to my original question. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Syntax errors? Does your code include the semi-colons under parameter map, because they are missing from what you posted.  Just realized they are missing in what I posted.

Comment: Just for reference, [here is a link to an answer I previously posted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24004905/kendo-ui-grid-multi-level-hierarchy-n-levels-of-hierarchy/24310780#24310780) with full code examples.  If I have time I'll create a fiddle to demonstrate.

Comment: I would very much appreciate a fiddle. I just cannot get this to work.

Comment: Please add it as an answer when you get a chance.