# Editor for ViewModel with in-memory datasource

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm facing a situation where I need to display a editor for this view-model:

```
public class ParkingServiceDetailViewModel : ViewModelBase, IValidatableObject
{

    public ParkingServiceDetailViewModel()
    {
        ParkingCardIssueDate = DateTime.Now;
        ParkingCardExpiryDate = ParkingCardIssueDate.Value.AddYears(1);
    }

    [Display(Name = "Parking Service Id")]
    public int? ParkingServiceId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Terminal")]
    public int? TerminalId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Service")]
    public int? ServiceId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Card Number")]
    public string ParkingCardNumber { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Card Issue Date")]
    public DateTime? ParkingCardIssueDate { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Card Expiry Date")]
    public DateTime? ParkingCardExpiryDate { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Card Group")]
    public string ParkingCardGroup { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (TerminalId < 0)
        {
            yield return new ValidationResult("Terminal Id is required.", new[] { "TerminalId" });
        }
    }
}
```

Now, this view-model is a child (as a List<>) in another view-model. I'm trying to use Kendo Grid as an editor and here is a what I have so far:

```
@model List<DA.Services.CarPark.Presentation.Web.Models.ParkingServiceDetailViewModel>

<div id="parkingServiceDetails" style="margin-top:10px">

    @(Html.Kendo().Grid<DA.Services.CarPark.Presentation.Web.Models.ParkingServiceDetailViewModel>()
        .Name("ServiceList")
        .Columns(columns => {
            columns.Bound(p => p.ParkingCardNumber);

            columns.Bound(p => p.ParkingCardIssueDate).Width(115)
                .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "templateCell" })
                .ClientTemplate(Html.Kendo().DatePicker()
                    .Name("IssueDate_#=TerminalId#_#=ServiceId#")
                    .Culture("ar-AE")
                    .HtmlAttributes(new { data_bind = "value:IssueDate" })
                    .ToClientTemplate().ToString());

            columns.Bound(p => p.ParkingCardExpiryDate).Width(115)
                .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "templateCell" })
                .ClientTemplate(Html.Kendo().DatePicker()
                    .Name("ExpiryDate_#=TerminalId#_#=ServiceId#")
                    .Culture("ar-AE")
                    .HtmlAttributes(new { data_bind = "value:ExpiryDate" })
                    .ToClientTemplate().ToString());

            columns.Bound(p => p.ParkingCardGroup);
        })
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Ajax()
            .ServerOperation(false)
            .Model(model => {
                model.Id(p => p.ParkingServiceId);
                model.Field(p => p.ParkingServiceId).DefaultValue(new Kendo.Mvc.ClientHandlerDescriptor() { HandlerName = "defaultValue" });
                model.Field(p => p.TerminalId);
                model.Field(p => p.ServiceId);
                model.Field(p => p.ParkingCardNumber);
                model.Field(p => p.ParkingCardIssueDate);
                model.Field(p => p.ParkingCardExpiryDate);
                model.Field(p => p.ParkingCardGroup);
            })
            .Create(create => create.Action("Index", "CardRequest"))
         )
         .Editable(e => e.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))
         .Events(ev => ev.DataBound("db"))
         .ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Create())
         .Scrollable()
         .AllowCopy(true)
         .Selectable()
         .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height: 350px" })
    )

</div>

<script>
    function defaultValue(e) {
        if (typeof this.ParkingServiceId === "function") {
            var grid = $("#ServiceList").data("kendoGrid");
            var ds = grid.dataSource;
            var filter = ds.filter();

            if (filter && filter.filters[0].field === "ParkingServiceId") {
                return filter.filters[0].value;
            } else {
                return 1;
            }
        }
    }

    function db(e) {
        var grid = this;
        $(".templateCell").each(function () {
            eval($(this).children("script").last().html());
            var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
            var item = grid.dataItem(tr);
            kendo.bind($(this), item);
        });
    }
</script>
```

What I have seen so far is that the Kendo Grid's datasource has no in-memory alternate. Even in custom mode, I was not able to use a local source. I don't want to put up a CRUD API for a simple data structure.

Simultaneously, [I have been trying a much harder way to accomplish the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37181714/loop-generating-kendo-dropdownlistfor-in-jquery-doesnt-initialize-properly). In that case, everything is hand crafted on client side. The issue here is the Kendo UI controls/wrappers (DropdownList, DateTimePicker) <strike>become dead at runtime. No clicks, no inputs, and no errors. Whereas, regular controls work properly.</strike> But due to aesthetics, I need to stick with Kendo all the way. In the second approach, there is a lot of overhead I have to worry about especially the ordering of the List and naming. Something, while doing that, renders only Kendo wrapper in a strange disabled state.

But my main focus is to use the grid as it suits the purpose. Unfortunately I cannot explore any more options like Angular to overcome this issue. Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by in-memory? If you are going to enter data into this view, don't you need to save it somewhere? Or maybe back up a step and give some background on the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: I don't want to push a simple `List<ParkingServiceDetailViewModel>` back and forth and was hoping to have it done within the EditorTemplate. In the end when the user submits, the `List<ParkingServiceDetailViewModel>` is available as a property of the parent ViewModel

Comment: If the `ParkingServiceDetailViewModel` is a child, why not put it into a sub-grid?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24004905/kendo-ui-grid-multi-level-hierarchy-n-levels-of-hierarchy/24310780#24310780

Comment: The pointed SO question is an excellent example. But my issue is that once I do get the grid ON, I have cascading combos i need to tackle AND the datasource is still expecting a bind to a service.

Comment: The datasource doesn't have to be a service.  The datasource can be a collection.  It all depends on the level of interactivity.  If the child grid is finite (you don't need to go to the server for more rows), then you can get the data you need and initialize the child grid from that result.

Comment: But what type of `datasource : {}` do I setup for that?

Comment: In the n-tier example I posted, the function `detailInit` is used to initialize the child grid, passing `result` into a function `initializeDetailGrid(e, result)`, setting `datasource: result`.  In this case it is the JSON result from the POST. You could accomplish the same thing via a promise or callback.