# Loop-generating Kendo DropDownListFor in jQuery doesn't initialize properly

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to create an Editor Template for a ViewModel and I see that Kendo controls are facing issues after being generated.

Here is the `ParkingServiceDetail.cshtml` file:

```
@model List<DA.Services.CarPark.Presentation.Web.Models.ParkingServiceDetailViewModel>

<div id="@ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix" style="margin-top:10px">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover" id="grid">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th data-field="TerminalId">Terminal</th>
                <th data-field="ServiceId">Service</th>
                <th data-field="ParkingCardNumber">Card Number</th>
                <th data-field="ParkingCardIssueDate">Issue Date</th>
                <th data-field="ParkingCardExpiryDate">Expiry Date</th>
                <th data-field="ParkingCardGroup">Card Group</th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @if (Model != null && Model.Any())
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
                {
                    <tr mjrole="@(Model[i].ParkingCardNumber == "viewtemplate" ? "template" : "row")" style="display:@(Model[i].ParkingCardNumber == "viewtemplate" ? "none" : "")">
                        <td>@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m[i].TerminalId, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Terminals, "Select terminal", new { @class = "form-control", style = "width:150px", mjrole = ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix + "-terminal" })</td>
                        <td>@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m[i].ServiceId, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Services, "Select service", new { @class = "form-control", style = "width:150px", mjrole = ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix + "-service" })</td>
                        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[i].ParkingCardNumber,     new { @class = "k-textbox form-control" })</td>
                        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[i].ParkingCardIssueDate,  new { @class = "form-control", style = "width:115px", mjrole = "dateIs" })</td>
                        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[i].ParkingCardExpiryDate, new { @class = "form-control", style = "width:115px", mjrole = "dateEx" })</td>
                        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[i].ParkingCardGroup,      new { @class = "k-textbox form-control", style = "width:100px" })</td>
                        <td>
                            <button command="@ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix-delete" id="DeptFlightSearch" type="button" class="btn btn-danger @(Model[i].TerminalId > 0 ? "disabled" : "")">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></span>
                                Delete
                            </button>
                        </td>

                        <script type="text/javascript">

                            var tempParent = $("select[mjrole='@ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix-terminal']")
                                .kendoDropDownList({
                                    optionLabel: "Select terminal...",
                                    dataTextField: "TerminalName",
                                    dataValueField: "TerminalId",
                                    dataSource: {
                                        serverFiltering: true,
                                        transport: {
                                            read: {
                                                url: "Ajax/GetTerminals",
                                                dataType: "json"
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                });

                            $("select[mjrole='@ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix-service']")
                                .kendoDropDownList({
                                    autoBind: false,
                                    cascadeFrom: tempParent.id,
                                    optionLabel: "Select service...",
                                    dataTextField: "NameEnglish",
                                    dataValueField: "Code",
                                    dataSource: {
                                        serverFiltering: true,
                                        transport: {
                                            read: {
                                                url: "Ajax/GetTerminalServices",
                                                data: "filterServices",
                                                dataType: "json"
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                });

                        </script>
                    </tr>
                }
            }

            <tr id="@ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix-empty" style="display: @(Model != null && Model[0].ParkingCardNumber == "viewtemplate" && Model.Count > 1 ? "none": "")">
                <td colspan="7">
                    No services added
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr mjrole="footer">
                <td colspan="7" style="text-align: right;">
                    <button id="@ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix-AddNew" type="button" class="btn btn-outline btn-success btn-circle btn-lg">
                        <span class="fa fa-plus"></span>
                    </button>
                </td>
            </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="@ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix-popup" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="dialog" style="width:700px">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h3 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Confirmation</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <h5> Are you sure you want to delete the selected service? </h5>
                <table class="table table-bordered table-striped" id="deletegrid"></table>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline btn-danger btn-circle btn-lg" data-dismiss="modal">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
                </button>
                <button id="@ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix-ok" type="button" class="btn btn-outline btn-success btn-circle btn-lg">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $("#@ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix").on("click", "button[command='@ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix-delete']", function (arg) {
        var row = $(arg.target).parent().closest("tr");
        $('#@ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix').prop("target", row);
        $('#@ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix-popup').modal('show');
    });

    $("#@ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix-ok").click(function () {
        var row = $('#@ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix').prop("target");

        row.remove();

        $("#@ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix").find("tr[mjrole='row']").each(function (index) {
            var tempControl;

            tempControl = $(this).find("[id$='TerminalId']");
            tempControl.attr("id",   "@(ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix)_" + (index + 1) + "__TerminalId");
            tempControl.attr("name", "@(ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix)[" + (index + 1) + "].TerminalId");

            tempControl = $(this).find("[id$='ServiceId']");
            tempControl.attr("id",   "@(ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix)_" + (index + 1) + "__ServiceId");
            tempControl.attr("name", "@(ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix)[" + (index + 1) + "].ServiceId");

            tempControl = $(this).find("[id$='ParkingCardNumber']");
            tempControl.attr("id",   "@(ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix)_" + (index + 1) + "__ParkingCardNumber");
            tempControl.attr("name", "@(ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix)[" + (index + 1) + "].ParkingCardNumber");

            tempControl = $(this).find("[id$='ParkingCardIssueDate']");
            tempControl.attr("id",   "@(ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix)_" + (index + 1) + "__ParkingCardIssueDate");
            tempControl.attr("name", "@(ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix)[" + (index + 1) + "].ParkingCardIssueDate");

            tempControl = $(this).find("[id$='ParkingCardExpiryDate']");
            tempControl.attr("id",   "@(ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix)_" + (index + 1) + "__ParkingCardExpiryDate");
            tempControl.attr("name", "@(ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix)[" + (index + 1) + "].ParkingCardExpiryDate");

            tempControl = $(this).find("[id$='ParkingCardGroup']");
            tempControl.attr("id",   "@(ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix)_" + (index + 1) + "__ParkingCardGroup");
            tempControl.attr("name", "@(ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix)[" + (index + 1) + "].ParkingCardGroup");
        });

        $('#@ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix-popup').modal('hide');

        if ($("#@ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix table tr[mjrole='row']").length > 0) {
            $("#@ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix-empty").hide();
        }
        else {
            $("#@ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix-empty").show();
        }
    });

    $("#@ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix-AddNew").click(function () {
        var row;

        if ($("#@ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix table tr[mjrole='template']").length > 0) {
            row = $("#@ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix table tr[mjrole='template']").clone();
        }
        else {
            row = $("#@ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix table tr[mjrole='row']").first().clone();
        }

        row.attr("mjrole", "row").show();
        row.find("input[name$='ParkingCardNumber']").val("");
        row.insertAfter($("#@ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix table tr").not($("#@ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix table tr[mjrole='footer']")).last());

        if ($("#@ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix table tr[mjrole='row']").length > 0) {
            $("#@ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix-empty").hide();
        }
        else {
            $("#@ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix-empty").show();
        }

        $("#@ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix").find("tr[mjrole='row']").each(function (index) {
            var tempControl;

            tempControl = $(this).find("[id$='TerminalId']");
            tempControl.attr("id",   "@(ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix)_" + (index + 1) + "__TerminalId");
            tempControl.attr("name", "@(ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix)[" + (index + 1) + "].TerminalId");

            tempControl = $(this).find("[id$='ServiceId']");
            tempControl.attr("id",   "@(ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix)_" + (index + 1) + "__ServiceId");
            tempControl.attr("name", "@(ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix)[" + (index + 1) + "].ServiceId");

            tempControl = $(this).find("[id$='ParkingCardNumber']");
            tempControl.attr("id",   "@(ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix)_" + (index + 1) + "__ParkingCardNumber");
            tempControl.attr("name", "@(ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix)[" + (index + 1) + "].ParkingCardNumber");

            tempControl = $(this).find("[id$='ParkingCardIssueDate']");
            tempControl.attr("id",   "@(ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix)_" + (index + 1) + "__ParkingCardIssueDate");
            tempControl.attr("name", "@(ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix)[" + (index + 1) + "].ParkingCardIssueDate");

            tempControl = $(this).find("[id$='ParkingCardExpiryDate']");
            tempControl.attr("id",   "@(ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix)_" + (index + 1) + "__ParkingCardExpiryDate");
            tempControl.attr("name", "@(ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix)[" + (index + 1) + "].ParkingCardExpiryDate");

            tempControl = $(this).find("[id$='ParkingCardGroup']");
            tempControl.attr("id",   "@(ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix)_" + (index + 1) + "__ParkingCardGroup");
            tempControl.attr("name", "@(ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix)[" + (index + 1) + "].ParkingCardGroup");
        });

        $("input[mjrole='dateIs']").kendoDatePicker({ culture: "ar-AE" });
        $("input[mjrole='dateEx']").kendoDatePicker({ culture: "ar-AE" });

    });

    function filterServices() {
        return {
            companyId: '@ViewData["CompanyId"]',
            terminalId: $("#TerminalId").val()
        };
    }

</script>
```

It seem intimidating but only because of list ordering workaround. This is pretty basic stuff.

I was originally using the Html.Helpers controls and they work OK. However, I need to manage a few cascading drop-downs in each row. And that's why you see the script tag right after the  generation.

Issue is that the widget initiation was failing for all Kendo controls. I solved the DatePicker by initiating them after the Add Button code in JS. But they are not really dependent so that was easy. I cannot do the same for the two drop-downs though.

Currently, at runtime, the two drop-downs get converted to Kendo and are in a sort of disabled state and do not accept any inputs or respond to any attribute changes through browser debuggers.

And I have confirmed that if I move the bit of JS from tr generation to after Add button click, it works but I lose ids that I need create cascading dependencies.

Is there some threading timing issues here that fail in case of Kendo but not the regular controls?

**Update**

Main issue I identified was the names of the Kendo controls were not unique. New code in my answer below. This resolves 50% of the question.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do, but it's clear that you're doing it the wrong way. Whatever you want to do can be done using partial views and ajax.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the blocked out kendo controls by naming them properly. Now for the existing records (if I send a few in the List<>), the rows render correctly with proper kendo controls. However, for new inserted rows, the same issue comes back as I have yet to figure out how to rename in that scenario.

Also, the cascading combos are not working either.

Here is the working code:

```
@model List<DA.Services.CarPark.Presentation.Web.Models.ParkingServiceDetailViewModel>

<div id="@ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix" style="margin-top:10px">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover" id="grid">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th data-field="TerminalId">Terminal</th>
                <th data-field="ServiceId">Service</th>
                <th data-field="ParkingCardNumber">Card Number</th>
                <th data-field="ParkingCardIssueDate">Issue Date</th>
                <th data-field="ParkingCardExpiryDate">Expiry Date</th>
                <th data-field="ParkingCardGroup">Card Group</th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @if (Model != null && Model.Any())
            {
                for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
                {
                    <tr mjrole="@(Model[i].ParkingCardNumber == "viewtemplate" ? "template" : "row")" style="display: @(Model[i].ParkingCardNumber == "viewtemplate" ? "none" : "")">
                        <td>@(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m[i].TerminalId)
                            .Name(ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix + "[" + (i + 1) + "].TerminalId")
                            .OptionLabel("Select terminal...")
                            .DataTextField("TerminalName")
                            .DataValueField("TerminalId")
                            .DataSource(source => source
                                .Read(read => read
                                    .Action("GetTerminals", "Ajax")
                                    .Type(HttpVerbs.Post)
                                )
                            )
                            .HtmlAttributes(new {
                                @class = "form-control", style = "width:150px",
                                mjrole = ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix + "-terminal"
                            })
                            )
                        </td>
                        <td>@(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m[i].ServiceId)
                            .Name(ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix + "[" + (i + 1) + "].ServiceId")
                            .OptionLabel("Select service...")
                            .DataTextField("NameEnglish")
                            .DataValueField("Code")
                            .AutoBind(false)
                            .CascadeFrom(ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix + "_" + (i + 1) + "__TerminalId")
                            .DataSource(source => source
                                .Read(read => read
                                    .Action("GetTerminalServices", "Ajax")
                                    .Type(HttpVerbs.Post)
                                )
                            )
                            .HtmlAttributes(new {
                                 @class = "form-control", style = "width:150px",
                                 mjrole = ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix + "-service"
                            })
                            )
                        </td>
                        <td>@(Html.Kendo().TextBoxFor(   m => m[i].ParkingCardNumber)    .Name(ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix + "[" + (i + 1) + "].ParkingCardNumber")    .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "form-control" }))</td>
                        <td>@(Html.Kendo().DatePickerFor(m => m[i].ParkingCardIssueDate) .Name(ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix + "[" + (i + 1) + "].ParkingCardIssueDate") .Culture("ar-AE").HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "form-control", style = "width:115px", mjrole = "dateIs" }))</td>
                        <td>@(Html.Kendo().DatePickerFor(m => m[i].ParkingCardExpiryDate).Name(ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix + "[" + (i + 1) + "].ParkingCardExpiryDate").Culture("ar-AE").HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "form-control", style = "width:115px", mjrole = "dateEx" }))</td>
                        <td>@(Html.Kendo().TextBoxFor(   m => m[i].ParkingCardGroup)     .Name(ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix + "[" + (i + 1) + "].ParkingCardGroup")     .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "form-control", style = "width: 100px" }))</td>
                        <td>
                            <button command="@ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix-delete" id="DeptFlightSearch" type="button" class="btn btn-danger @(Model[i].TerminalId > 0 ? "disabled" : "")">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></span>
                                Delete
                            </button>
                        </td>

                        <script>
                            var tempDropdown = $('#@ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix' + '_@(i + 1)__TerminalId').data("kendoDropDownList");
                            $("#" + @ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix + "_" + (i + 1) + "__ServiceId").data("kendoDropDownList").dataSource().read().transport().data(function(){return {companyId : @ViewBag.CompanyId, terminalId : tempDropdown.value() }} );
                        </script>
                    </tr>
                }
            }

            <tr id="@ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix-empty" style="display: @(Model != null && Model[0].ParkingCardNumber == "viewtemplate" && Model.Count > 1 ? "none": "")">
                <td colspan="7">
                    No services added
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr mjrole="footer">
                <td colspan="7" style="text-align: right;">
                    <button id="@ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix-AddNew" type="button" class="btn btn-outline btn-success btn-circle btn-lg">
                        <span class="fa fa-plus"></span>
                    </button>
                </td>
            </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="@ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix-popup" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="dialog" style="width:700px">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h3 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Confirmation</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <h5> Are you sure you want to delete the selected service? </h5>
                <table class="table table-bordered table-striped" id="deletegrid"></table>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline btn-danger btn-circle btn-lg" data-dismiss="modal">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
                </button>
                <button id="@ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix-ok" type="button" class="btn btn-outline btn-success btn-circle btn-lg">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $("#@ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix").on("click", "button[command='@ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix-delete']", function (arg) {
        var row = $(arg.target).parent().closest("tr");
        $('#@ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix').prop("target", row);
        $('#@ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix-popup').modal('show');
    });

    $("#@ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix-ok").click(function () {
        var row = $('#@ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix').prop("target");

        row.remove();

        $("#@ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix").find("tr[mjrole='row']").each(function (index) {
            var tempControl;

            tempControl = $(this).find("[id$='TerminalId']");
            tempControl.attr("id",   "@(ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix)_" + (index + 1) + "__TerminalId");
            tempControl.attr("name", "@(ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix)[" + (index + 1) + "].TerminalId");

            tempControl = $(this).find("[id$='ServiceId']");
            tempControl.attr("id",   "@(ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix)_" + (index + 1) + "__ServiceId");
            tempControl.attr("name", "@(ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix)[" + (index + 1) + "].ServiceId");

            tempControl = $(this).find("[id$='ParkingCardNumber']");
            tempControl.attr("id",   "@(ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix)_" + (index + 1) + "__ParkingCardNumber");
            tempControl.attr("name", "@(ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix)[" + (index + 1) + "].ParkingCardNumber");

            tempControl = $(this).find("[id$='ParkingCardIssueDate']");
            tempControl.attr("id",   "@(ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix)_" + (index + 1) + "__ParkingCardIssueDate");
            tempControl.attr("name", "@(ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix)[" + (index + 1) + "].ParkingCardIssueDate");

            tempControl = $(this).find("[id$='ParkingCardExpiryDate']");
            tempControl.attr("id",   "@(ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix)_" + (index + 1) + "__ParkingCardExpiryDate");
            tempControl.attr("name", "@(ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix)[" + (index + 1) + "].ParkingCardExpiryDate");

            tempControl = $(this).find("[id$='ParkingCardGroup']");
            tempControl.attr("id",   "@(ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix)_" + (index + 1) + "__ParkingCardGroup");
            tempControl.attr("name", "@(ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix)[" + (index + 1) + "].ParkingCardGroup");
        });

        $('#@ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix-popup').modal('hide');

        if ($("#@ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix table tr[mjrole='row']").length > 0) {
            $("#@ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix-empty").hide();
        }
        else {
            $("#@ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix-empty").show();
        }
    });

    $("#@ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix-AddNew").click(function () {
        var row;

        if ($("#@ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix table tr[mjrole='template']").length > 0) {
            row = $("#@ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix table tr[mjrole='template']").clone();
        }
        else {
            row = $("#@ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix table tr[mjrole='row']").first().clone();
        }

        row.attr("mjrole", "row").show();
        row.find("input[name$='ParkingCardNumber']").val("");
        row.insertAfter($("#@ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix table tr").not($("#@ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix table tr[mjrole='footer']")).last());

        if ($("#@ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix table tr[mjrole='row']").length > 0) {
            $("#@ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix-empty").hide();
        }
        else {
            $("#@ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix-empty").show();
        }

        $("#@ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix").find("tr[mjrole='row']").each(function (index) {
            var tempControl;

            tempControl = $(this).find("[id$='TerminalId']");
            tempControl.attr("id",   "@(ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix)_" + (index + 1) + "__TerminalId");
            tempControl.attr("name", "@(ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix)[" + (index + 1) + "].TerminalId");

            tempControl = $(this).find("[id$='ServiceId']");
            tempControl.attr("id",   "@(ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix)_" + (index + 1) + "__ServiceId");
            tempControl.attr("name", "@(ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix)[" + (index + 1) + "].ServiceId");

            tempControl = $(this).find("[id$='ParkingCardNumber']");
            tempControl.attr("id",   "@(ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix)_" + (index + 1) + "__ParkingCardNumber");
            tempControl.attr("name", "@(ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix)[" + (index + 1) + "].ParkingCardNumber");

            tempControl = $(this).find("[id$='ParkingCardIssueDate']");
            tempControl.attr("id",   "@(ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix)_" + (index + 1) + "__ParkingCardIssueDate");
            tempControl.attr("name", "@(ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix)[" + (index + 1) + "].ParkingCardIssueDate");

            tempControl = $(this).find("[id$='ParkingCardExpiryDate']");
            tempControl.attr("id",   "@(ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix)_" + (index + 1) + "__ParkingCardExpiryDate");
            tempControl.attr("name", "@(ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix)[" + (index + 1) + "].ParkingCardExpiryDate");

            tempControl = $(this).find("[id$='ParkingCardGroup']");
            tempControl.attr("id",   "@(ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix)_" + (index + 1) + "__ParkingCardGroup");
            tempControl.attr("name", "@(ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix)[" + (index + 1) + "].ParkingCardGroup");
        });
    });

    function filterServices() {
        return {
            companyId: '@ViewData["CompanyId"]',
            terminalId: $("#TerminalId").val()
        };
    }

</script>
```