# Loading parent and child nodes from remote data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

I've got a method in my controller that returns a `List<TreeViewItemModel>()` that I'm populating with the correct hierarchy. This seems to serialize correctly, but when I load the Treeview, I don't have any of the hierarchy, just the first level of nodes.

Example:

[image: Treeview]

Each of the above Curricula has 2/3 scenarios underneath that I've verified are getting added as items to the base object when going from curriculum => TreeViewItemModel

Controller:

```
public JsonResult GetAvailableCurricula(string LocationId)
{
    LocationId = "1";
    if(LocationId != string.Empty)
    {
        var results = Logic.GetFilteredCurriculum().Select(c => CurriculumToTreeView(c));
        return Json(results, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    else
    {
        return Json(new List<TreeViewItemModel>(),JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}

private TreeViewItemModel CurriculumToTreeView(CurriculumModel c)
{
    var tree = new TreeViewItemModel()
    {
        Id = c.CurriculumId.ToString(),
        Text = c.CurriculumName,
        HasChildren = c.Scenarios.Any()
    };

    if (tree.HasChildren)
    {
        tree.Items = c.Scenarios.Select(scenario =>
            new TreeViewItemModel()
            {
                Text = scenario.Name,      
            }
        ).ToList();    
    }
    return tree;
}
```

View:

```
@(Html.Kendo().TreeView()
.Name("AvailableCurricula")
.DataTextField("Text")
.DataSource(source => source
    .Read(read => read
        .Action("GetAvailableCurricula", "TraineeAssignments")
    .Data("filterAvailableCurricula")
    )
)
```

Is there some extra step I need to take to bind the child objects AND the parent, instead of just one level at a time? I have a fairly small set of data that I don't need to reload all that often, so I would was hoping to avoid loading each level individually/on-demand.

In case it's helpful, here's the raw JSON I'm sending from the controller for one of my curricula:

```
{"Enabled":true,"Expanded":false,"Encoded":true,"Selected":false,"Text":"Operator B","SpriteCssClass":null,"Id":"1","Url":null,"ImageUrl":null,"HasChildren":true,"Checked":false,"Items":[{"Enabled":true,"Expanded":false,"Encoded":true,"Selected":false,"Text":"test 2","SpriteCssClass":null,"Id":null,"Url":null,"ImageUrl":null,"HasChildren":false,"Checked":false,"Items":[],"HtmlAttributes":{},"ImageHtmlAttributes":{},"LinkHtmlAttributes":{}},{"Enabled":true,"Expanded":false,"Encoded":true,"Selected":false,"Text":"Scenario II","SpriteCssClass":null,"Id":null,"Url":null,"ImageUrl":null,"HasChildren":false,"Checked":false,"Items":[],"HtmlAttributes":{},"ImageHtmlAttributes":{},"LinkHtmlAttributes":{}}],"HtmlAttributes":{},"ImageHtmlAttributes":{},"LinkHtmlAttributes":{}}
```

Comment: the treeview takes a hierarchical data source.  what does the serialized data look like?

Comment: I'm returning a List<TreeViewItemModel>() to the Treeview, and I'm manually setting the hierarchy in my CurriculumToTreeview method. I've got another page that uses those objects, and it works fine. The only difference is that page uses local data, retrieved from ViewBag, and this one uses remote data. I'll add the raw JSON to my post if that'll help.

Comment: Do you get data if you directly call `TraineeAssignments\GetAvailableCurricula`?

Comment: Yes, that's how I got that raw JSON string I posted above.

Answer (score -1):

I believe that the remote data option for the Treeview uses ajax to load the child data, either on demand or at initial load - controlled by the `LoadOnDemand` [option](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/aspnet-mvc/Kendo.Mvc.UI.Fluent/TreeViewBuilder#methods-LoadOnDemand%28System.Boolean%29).

The [remote data examples](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/treeview/remote-data-binding) in the kendo docs behave that way.  That is how I implemented it on [a previous project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24004905/kendo-ui-grid-multi-level-hierarchy-n-levels-of-hierarchy/24310780#24310780). The full code example includes a treeview as well as a grid.

Comment: I tried adding LoadOnDemand(false) to my TreeView, and it looks like nothing changed and only the parent objects are displayed. Because my objects are different types, curricula and scenarios, instead of all Employees like in Kendo's example, is there a way to at least have a different load method for child objects, if I can't get the entire hierarchy to load at the outset?

Comment: I know that remote data can be loaded via a function, which in turn makes the appropriate ajax call.  I'll see if I can come up with some kind of an example (or you can experiment some in that direction as well).